# sleep a python loop to iterate at exact times

Tags: python, loops, datetime, time

I have a Python 3 script that will run an infinite loop, 24/7. It makes a website connection and goes to a certain webpage to download a file.

Each iteration will take about a minute, but I need the script to start each iteration at exact times, about 5 minutes apart. For instance: at 1 minute after the hour, 6 minutes after the hour, 11 minutes after the hour, etc. I need the script to sleep between iterations until the exact time to start again. Just wondering if there's a clean way to do this?

EDIT: Based on answers given so far, I think I need to re-phrase my question. Basically, what is needed is to calculate the time between the time the last iteration ended and when I want the next iteration to begin. In other words, I need the difference between now, the current time, and the next time the minute of the time is either 01, 06, 11, 16, 21, 26, 31, 36, 41, 46, 51, 56 and the seconds of the time is 00. Then I can time.sleep() the script for that amount of time.

Comment: Is the infinite loop required? Ensuring a program acts at a precise time is very difficult because the OS has control. If the script only runs one iteration you can use a crontab to control when each iteration is launched.

Comment: I'm using Selenium to go to the webpage and I need the connection to the website kept open so I I can grab the download link at the exact time. Much easier to just stay on the page than to log in/log out every time, I think.

Comment: Well, webpages are stateless... so it's not actually that different. Also, you can't keep a web connection open in perpetuity.

Comment: As said below use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and simply sleep 5 seconds after each download with `sleep(5)`

Comment: How much precision do you need? If you're five seconds off, is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, I need it exact (or as close as possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I believe they call this a "kludge". I posted the below with a bunch of comments and print lines left in for clarification and to see how this works. In any event, this seems to be working pretty well. Each loop will begin (except the first loop) at either ?1:30 and ?6:30, exactly 5 minutes apart and within just a few milliseconds of when the loop is due to start. Of course, it will need to be edited if you decide to use it but, maybe this is a helpful start.

```
##### import modules
import time
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
##### create list of possible loop start times; this here creates start times every 5 minutes, starting the loops at 01:30, 06:30, 11:30, etc., after the hour
dt_cur = datetime.now()
dt_4_list = datetime.strptime(str(dt_cur.year) + '-' + str(dt_cur.month) + '-' + str(dt_cur.day) + ' ' + str(dt_cur.hour) + ':1:30', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ls_dt = [dt_4_list]
for i in range(288):
    dt_4_list = dt_4_list + timedelta(minutes = 5)
    ls_dt.append(dt_4_list)
##### begin the loop
loop_timer = 0
while loop_timer < 275:
    if loop_timer > 0:
        ##### check if the loop started before the exact time due to time.sleep() not being exactly accurate
        time_check = datetime.now().strftime("%S.%f")
        time_check = float(time_check)
        loop_time_check = 0
        while time_check < 30 and loop_time_check < 100:
            time_check = datetime.now().strftime("%S.%f")
            time_check = float(time_check)
            print(time_check, '- WARNING: time_check < 30; loop =', loop_time_check + 1, flush=True)
            time.sleep(.025)
            loop_time_check += 1
            if loop_time_check == 100:
                print(time_check, '- WARNING: exiting script early; time_check < 30 100 times', flush=True)
                raise SystemExit()
    ########################################################################################################################
    ##### start doing  stuff here ##########################################################################################
    dt_cur = datetime.now()
    print(dt_cur, flush=True)
    for i in range(5):          ##### this is where your own script does it's work before resting until the next loop
        print(i, flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
    ##### end doing stuff here #############################################################################################
    ########################################################################################################################
    ##### create the current datetime var
    dt_cur = datetime.now()
    print(dt_cur, flush=True)
    ##### create the dt_next_loop time var, increment the loop
    for d in ls_dt:
        if d > dt_cur:
            dt_next_loop = d
            break
    loop_timer += 1
    ##### get the seconds to sleep the script but make it about 5 seconds short of the actual time to begin the next loop
    sleep_secs = (dt_next_loop - dt_cur) - timedelta(seconds=5)
    sleep_secs = timedelta.total_seconds(sleep_secs)
    time.sleep(sleep_secs)
    ##### sleep the script about 5 seconds more before the actual time to begin the next loop (sleep.time() is not precisely accurate
    ##### over minutes and doing this again 5 seconds before the time to begin the next loop will ensure more accuracy)
    sleep_secs = datetime.now().strftime("%S.%f")
    sleep_secs = 30 - float(sleep_secs)
    time.sleep(sleep_secs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the requests library for making web connections and put the script in a cron job to have it run every 5 min.